# Related product attributes in nopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I am running nopCommerce 3.10 and have a requirement to have two related product attributes:

One is a radio button list with yes/no options

The second is a text box.  I already have the radio buttons set to be required with no default, so the customer has to select one of them.
If they select 'Yes' I would like the text box to be required as well.  But not if they select 'no'.  Is this kind of thing possible out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, conditional attributes are not supported yet

Comment: Indeed. I ended up developing my own solution for this in the end